# How to use Spring Websocket with the Spring Session custom HttpSession and without Stomp/SockJS?

Tags: java, spring, session, websocket

In an server application I use **bare websockets without** the **spring messaging** layer and **sockjs/stomp**. I need my own messaging layer on top, but I want to **use for example spring session to leverage the servlet HttpSession replacement** to keep the http session alive which is beneath the websocket session, to prevent timeouts. The *websocket is opened from a static HTML-page* using JavaScript.

In the [spring-framework documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#websocket) there is all the necessary information to **setup bare websocket** support with e.g. a basic **BinaryWebSocketHandler** or TextWebSocketHandler as well as how to
provide your own **HandshakeInterceptor**.

I've added [spring session 1.1.0.RC1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/1.1.0.RC1/reference/html5/) with hazelcast for storing sessions and replacing the servlet container HttpSession implementation with the **Session/ExpiringSession** proivided by spring session. I just followed the given instructions to do this.

So far everything is fine, but as I'm **serving a static HTML** page from which I **open the websocket using JavaScript** without using spring security or any other mechanism to trigger a processing by the servlet container, **no http session is intialized so far**.

So the question is: **How do I intitialze the custom HttpSession which is then stored in a the SessionRepository provided by spring session?**

**Note:** I will provide an answer myself as I think I solved the issue for my case and it may be helpful for others facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen from the spring-framework documentation, it is possible to **add a custom HandshakeInterceptor**. Spring session offers the

```
// example for reference: 
org.springframework.session.web.socket.server.SessionRepositoryMessageInterceptor
```

which targets the spring messaging layer. It **shows how to reset the timer of the HttpSession** prior to sending a message within the method *preSend(...)* as well as how to **optain the HttpSession from the request** in the method *beforeHandshake(...)*.

I implemented my **own HandshakeInterceptor** based on this with an **almost identical beforeHandshake(...) method**, but with one minor difference and of course leaving out the ChannelInterceptorAdapter stuff. The reset of the HttpSession time has to be done somewhere else, but that is out-of-scope.

Because in my case no HttpSession has been created so far, I changed the line obtaining the session from the request to look like this:

```
HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession(true);
```

**Changing the boolean parameter from false to true** in the **method getSession(...)**. Now this call will trigger the creation of a new HttpSession (provided by spring session) if none is available so far.

This solution seems to do what is required in my case. Please correct me if I'm missing something or using anything the wrong way.